# Is there a way to know what called my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and a problem came to me.
I have my normal popup when I click on the top right corner and I call that same popup in a new window with chrome.window.create from the context menu by right clicking on my screen.
The problem is that I couldn't find how to know if the popup was displayed by my window.create or just by clicking on the logo in the top right corner. Depending on what called my popup the information displayed are not really the same.

Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks
Update :
My popup page is controlled by a popup.html and a popup.js file.
I have a file that is called main.js that controls everything concerning my context menu
I call my popup page from my main.js file with this
[windows.create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p90DJ.png)
So as you can see I can call my popup page from two sources, the main.js file and when i click on the extension logo in the top right.
And my problem is to know what opened my popup page.

Comment: I am not getting properly what you did and tried so far as no code is give. I think you can send a parameter where your created button. So when you will click on your button, this parameter will be checked and if it is present then that popup was opened by clicking that button.

Comment: just updated my post @Fokrule

Answer (score 0):

Really the problem is not clear though the title suggest you should look in developer console > Network to see what's calling your html.

Comment: I just updated my explanations if that helps